# Nesting a CTE Expression in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a TSQL recursive CTE that generates a date range between two dates as follows:

```
Select
    Cast('2020-05-01' As DATETIME) 'DATE'
Union All
Select
    DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE)
From
    DATE_RANGE t
Where
    DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE) <= '2020-05-02'
```

That works fine, so executing that gives me two records as below:

```
01/05/2020
02/05/2020
```

Then I use that in another expression along with a second table, PEOPLE_RECORDS:

```
With
    DATE_RANGE As (
     Select
         Cast('2020-05-01' As DATETIME) 'DATE'
     Union All
     Select
         DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE)
     From
         DATE_RANGE t
     Where
         DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE) <= '2020-05-02'
    )
Select
    *
From
    DATE_RANGE,
    PEOPLE
```

I have deliberately not linked the two tables, because I need the two dates (or however many date records are in my chosen range) to duplicate for every record in my PEOPLE table.

So, if I have 20 records in PEOPLE and a date range of 2 days I would expect 40 records from this query. This also works fine, just thought it might help to give some background about what I am trying to achieve :)

Next I want to be able to package this up in a sub query and link to a third CONTACT table via a left outer join so I can count how many records exist in the third CONTACT table for every PEOPLE record for each date in the recursive CTE range. The left outer join is so I can still see the dates where no CONTACT records exist for each PEOPLE record.

I have tried nesting the whole thing inside another WITH query and also a SELECT query, but I am aware that can't be done from looking at other posts on Stack Overflow.

What I am not aware of is how to get what I need. Hopefully this explains what I am trying to achieve, sorry if it's confusing. I am also aware that there could be a completely different method of getting what I am after, so please feel free to suggest alternatives. One thing to bear in mind is that I am querying with read-only permissions, and cannot create functions or procedures to do this.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so we can understand a little better what you're trying to do? You can create a CTE for your date and people query. Would that help? ```, DATES_AND_PEOPLE AS (Select * From DATE_RANGE, PEOPLE)```

Comment: You are mistaken. Define a CTE for your cross join (and please use modern syntax so everyone knows that this was intentional) and then finally outer join this new CTE to your contact info.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what JMabee was saying, but without functions. Will something like this work?

```
With
    DATE_RANGE As (
     Select
         Cast('2020-05-01' As DATETIME) 'DATE'
     Union All
     Select
         DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE)
     From
         DATE_RANGE t
     Where
         DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE) <= '2020-05-02'
    )
, people_and_dates as ( 
    Select
        *
    From
        DATE_RANGE,
        PEOPLE
)
select * 
from people_and_dates
-- do other stuff here
```

Comment: YES! Thanks nickfinity, this has worked perfectly! And thanks everyone else for looking / answering :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a TVF that you can then JOIN against.  Consider this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPeopleDates(
    @dtStart datetime,
    @dtEnd datetime
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN
    With
        DATE_RANGE As (
         Select
             @dtStart 'DATE'
         Union All
         Select
             DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE)
         From
             DATE_RANGE t
         Where
             DateAdd(dd, 1, t.DATE) <= @dtEnd
        )
    Select
        *
    From
        DATE_RANGE
        CROSS JOIN People
```

Given I don't have your table definitions I cannot limit the columns the function returns, but you can narrow that down on your own.  You could then join against this such as:

```
SELECT t2.* 
    FROM getPeopleDates('5/1/20', '5/2/20') t1
    LEFT JOIN SomeTable t2 on t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID 
WHERE  t2.PersonID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, I am pretty sure the permissions of the user won't allow them to create their own functions (or procedures) so I was hoping to do this all in the Select query somehow.